# mapping properties of $(1-z)^i.$

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a question on the complex analysis of Conway "Functions of one complex variable" (pg.57 #28) about the mapping properties of $(1-z)^i$.
Can anyone describe me what does the exponent '$i$' mean? What does it do to $(1-z)$? I am confused.
Can i write in the following way? 
$(1-z)^i=e^{i \log (1-z)}=\cos (\log (1-z))+i \sin (\log (1-z))$

Comment: I guess you are correct.. let someone confirm it..

Comment: It seems hard to imagine that $i$ wouldn't refer to the imaginary unit when talking about complex numbers.